# How to archive/export all files changed since a specific revision with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, archive, revisions

Mercurial supports a handy archive command which allows you to export all files as they were in a specific revision (thanks to Ry4an for pointing this out in a comment) to another folder/zip file etc. This is done as follows:

```
hg archive -r REV destination
```

Is there a way to export only the files changed *since* a certain revision and to the head?

Thanks,
Boaz

Comment: You're misreading what `hg archive` does.  It's not " all files changed in a specific revision ", it's ***all files as they looked after a specific revision***.  So, `hg archive -r tip` gets you an archive of all the files as they are now, regardless of how many changed in that final (tip) revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment about your misinterpretation of what archive does.  Given that, it might not still be the case that you actually want a way to build an archive with only the files that have changed from revision X to revision Y, but just in case you really do, this will do it:

```
hg grep -r X:Y --all . | cut -d : -f 1 | sort -u | sed 's/^/-I /' | xargs echo hg archive
```